# Firing callback every x milliseconds during drag event (HTML5, Ember)

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have a Mixin:

```
DragEvents = Ember.Mixin.create( {
    attributeBindings: 'draggable',
    draggable: 'true',
    dragStart: function(event) {
        controller.onDragStartEvent(this);
    },
    drag: function(event) {
        // this is called for each 'movement' of the object being dragged
        // want to collect information about the events and fire a callback
        // once every 100 ms
    },
    dragEnd: function(event) {
        // want to fire one last callback with the remaining drag event coordinates
    }
});
```

In the drag function I'm interested in the coordinates of the mouse, which are given by

```
event.originalEvent.pageX, event.originalEvent.pageY
```

What I can't figure out is how to collect that information each time drag is called and fire a callback every 100 ms during the drag with a parameter that is an array of coordinates which I have collected.  When the dragEnd function is called I want to fire the callback with the remaining drag events (the ones that were collected but had not been sent in a previous callback).

The callback is

```
controller.onDragEvent(coordinatesArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ember run has its own trottle

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_throttle

*Ensure that the target method is never called more frequently than the specified spacing period.*

In your case the code would be

```
Ember.run.throttle(controller, 'onDragEvent',coordinatesArray, 100);
```

Good luck

Comment: This looks like what I want but when I try it I get "Object function has no method 'throttle'"

Comment: You should put the code inside drag: function, and for the error I have a question how do you set the controller variable

Comment: It's created by `controller = Em.Object.create( {onDragEvent:function(coordinates){}});`

Comment: can you provide a JSfiddle?

Comment: If you can edit the question and provide more complete code I could see where the problem is...

Comment: Pretty sure this is the answer. New question for a new problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457076/ember-run-throttle-object-function-has-no-method-throttle-in-ember-mixin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function every 100ms, you could use JQuery and `queue` function to concatenate the function calls: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

If you don't know JQuery, it is very easy to use. Follow this instructions: http://jquery.com/download/ and you are ready to use the `queue` function. An example would be:

```
yourFunction() {
   $( "span" ).text( any );
   setTimeout( showIt, 100 );
  .queue(function(sig){
   yourFunction();
   sig();
  })
}
```

Remember that in JQuery you can use this symbols `$("#id")` or `$(".class")` to reference a tag or a group of them.

Comment: This still gets called for every time drag gets called, it just gets called on a delay. I need it to only be called once every 100 ms.

Comment: I'm new to all of javascript (: