# (Ember.run.throttle) Object Function has no method 'throttle' in Ember.Mixin

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have a controller that defines onDragEvent:

```
controller = Em.Object.create( {
    onDragEvent: function() {
        console.log("Drag Event");
    }
});
```

And I have a Mixin:

```
Event = Ember.Mixin.create( {
    attributeBindings: 'draggable',
    draggable: 'true',
    drag: function (event) {
        Em.run.throttle(this, controller.onDragEvent, 1000);
    }
});
```

My understanding is that during the drag the controller.onDragEvent should be called once every 1000 milliseconds.

The console is logging out:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){var d,e;f.begin();try{if(a||b)d=c(a,b,arguments,2)}finally{f.end()}return d} has no method 'throttle' Events.js:42
Events.Ember.Mixin.create.drag Events.js:42
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.trigger ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
d ember-1.0.pre.min.js:14
Ember.View.states.hasElement.handleEvent ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.invokeForState ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.handleEvent ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
c ember-1.0.pre.min.js:14
Ember.run ember-1.0.pre.min.js:14
Ember.EventDispatcher.Ember.Object.extend._bubbleEvent ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.pre.min.js:16
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
h.handle.i
```

I'm pretty sure I don't understand how to use the throttle feature.  I also notice that I am using `Em.Object.create` vs. `Ember.Mixin.create`, but calling the `controller.onDragEvent` without the throttle works fine.  What am I doing incorrectly?

edit 1:

if I use:

```
Event = Ember.Mixin.create( {
    attributeBindings: 'draggable',
    draggable: 'true',
    drag: function (event) {
        Em.run.throttle(controller, onDragEvent, 1000);
    }
});
```

I get a different error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onDragEvent is not defined
```

For reference; just calling `controller.onDragEvent();` works fine.

Comment: yeah, onDragEvent doesn't point to anything at that point, controller.onDragEvent is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized I never saw the right side of the stack.  You are on an older version of ember, the throttle and debounce features weren't introduced until late in 1.0 beta (1.0 RC7 to be exact, which is way after 1.0 pre)

Switch to this version:

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0/ember.js

It appears to be working for me:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oZIMiMA/1/edit

Highlight over a or b on the output.

Could you set up a jsbin showing it not working?

Example with draggable:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjZac/1/

```
DragNDrop.Draggable = Ember.Mixin.create({
  attributeBindings: 'draggable',
  draggable: 'true',
    drag: function(event) {
        console.log('real call')
         Ember.run.throttle(this, DragNDrop.controller.onDragEvent, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does controller exist within the context?

Comment: Looking at it, it is global, so it should exist.  What are you attaching your mixin to?

Comment: How can I check? If I just call `controller.onDragEvent();` it fires properly

Comment: This exhibits the behavior, but what I'm working with is MUCH more complex. For example I'm not sure how the controller and mixin are 'connected' but they are. This one..http://jsfiddle.net/jujodi/tjZac/. Just drag one of the first two boxes to see the error (I edited a random fiddle)

Comment: That's a very old version of Ember, let me update and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, I see that it works, but I have no idea what you did to make it work, it sounds like I have to update Ember? I'm running chromium in an ubuntu 12.04 vm

Comment: I just added the missing Droppable mixin.  If you aren't on version 1.0 of ember I would definitely suggest upgrading.  A lot has changed and been fixed.

Comment: When I add it to my fiddle it does not fix anything, and I don't understand how to translate that into the fix I actually need, which is not the fiddle.

Comment: You need to upgrade your version of ember, throttle and debounce weren't added until late 1.0.  What version of ember are you using?

Comment: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0/ember.js

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you'd like an event to fire every so often while dragging an element, and that event to prompt a function call within the controller.

You can use `throttle` to *stop a function from being called more often than the specified timeout period*. There is some documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_throttle. Does your issue persist if you declare the function before being called, rather than passing it in anonymously?

Your controller should probably extend from `Ember.ObjectController`, rather than `Ember.Object`, as an `ObjectController` comes with a bunch of convenience methods that will make accessing the controller as a controller - rather than a general-purpose object - much easier.

Comment: Your explanation of throttle makes sense, so how do I used it to make it so that the onDragEvent is called once every 1000 ms?

Comment: Does it help if you declare the function, rather than passing an anonymous function into `Em.run.throttle`?